# Export SQL table in CSV With Headers

Tags: mysql, excel, csv, phpmyadmin

I have a sql database in which i want to export some tables in CSV format. Users and purchases.

By using phpmyadmin, > Export function i've successfully exported all data in table but there are no headers (column title) in the excel sheet and its very confusing to determine data retrieved from that table.

its look like this:

[image]

And i need it like this: 
[image]

Any suggestion how to do this?

Comment: What happened when you Googled "phpmyadmin export csv with headers"? Please do that *before* asking here.

Comment: I did not find any post over the internet for phpmyadmin, I found some posts for sql server 2008

Comment: There's a format specific option for column names in the first row.

Comment: Yes! same no headers after checking "put name of columns in first row I've done all these methods then i decided to ask here to some experts

Comment: The Google search mentioned now redirects here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This works for me. What version of phpmyadmin do you have?

1. Under `Browse`, click on the table you want to export.
2. At the bottom, in the `Query results operations` section, click on `Export`.
3. In `Export method`, choose `Custom`.
4. Change `Format` to `CSV for MS Excel`.
5. Under `Format-specific options`, check `Put columns names in the first row`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Click on the export button
2. Export method custom
3. Format CSV
4. Format-specific options: Put columns names in the first row ( Select this checkbox)

[image]